# Machine Learning model to predict solar radiation with meteorological data as input

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to learn how to train some machine learning models using scikit learn.
The main goal is getting a model that predict the solar radiation with given meteorological data.

I've got an historical data of 2 years with meteorological data and solar radiation with hourly granularity. The meteorological have these columns:

| Column | Description | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| time | The datetime of the observation | Datetime64 |
| hour | Hour of the observation | String |
| Month | Month of the observation | String |
| temp | The air temperature in °C | Float64 |
| dwpt | The dew point in °C | Float64 |
| rhum | The relative humidity in percent (%) | Float64 |
| prcp | The one hour precipitation total in mm | Float64 |
| wdir | The average wind direction in degrees (°) | Float64 |
| wspd | The average wind speed in km/h | Float64 |
| wpgt | The peak wind gust in km/h | Float64 |
| pres | The average sea-level air pressure in hPa | Float64 |
| coco | The weather condition code | String |

As you can see, 3 columns have cathegorical values (hour, month, coco) and I'm treating this with OneHotEncoder.
For the models I've tested with MLP and Decision Tree Regressor but the results are not as good as I would like. This is part of the code that i'm using to transform the data and training the model:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.2)
train_data = X_train.join(y_train)


columns_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([
    ("cat", OneHotEncoder(), ["coco","month"]),
    ("time_hot", OneHotEncoder(), ["hour"]),
    ])

X_train = columns_pipeline.fit_transform(X_train)

tree_model = DecisionTreeRegressor()
tree_model.fit(X_train, y_train)

MLP_model = MLPRegressor(activation = 'relu', hidden_layer_sizes=(125))
MLP_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Since I'm new with this I would like to ask you if you have any other idea for data transformation , what other model i should try or if you consider something that i am doing wrong.
Maybe someone who have experience with making models for a problem like this could help me.

Thanks in advance!
Regards

Comment: I think this question is too open-ended to answer here; but the name for this is "time-series feature engineering." Since you're already using scikit-learn, you might explore [the documentation on the subject](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_cyclical_feature_engineering.html).

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=predict++solar+radiation "Google search for 'predict solar radiation'") leads me to believe this is a widely researched topic.  Perhaps some of the many ML papers will provide some inspiration.